# Simple real analysis problem on functions

Tags: real-analysis

Given that $f$ is one to one ($f:X \rightarrow Y$), show that $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ holds $\forall \ \ A,B \in \mathcal P (X)$ is an equivalent statement.

The proof goes like this:

If $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$, then $\exists$ $a \in A$,$b \in B$, such that $f(a)=f(b)=y$. Since $f$ is one-to-one, $a=b \in A \cap B$. Therefore, $y \in f(A \cap B)$. I can follow all of this, now the next statement is this:

"Thus, $f(A) \cap f(B) \subseteq f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$."

I have no clue how they arrived at that statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with $y \in f(A)\cap f(B)$, you have shown that $y\in f(A\cap B)$. However, in general, we also have that $f(A\cap B) \subset f(A)\cap f(B)$. You can show this using one line of element chasing. The chain which is written, $f(A)\cap f(B) \subset f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$ is a fancy way to write this mutual set inclusion. In other words, this is equivalent to saying $f(A\cap B)= f(A)\cap f(B)$.

Comment: Yeap. But where do they get this first part from:

$f(A) \cap f(B) \subseteq f(A \cap B)$

Comment: Do you mean showing that $f (A)\cap f (B) \subset f(A\cap B)$? This was exactly what the proof you copied shows. It takes an element from the first set and shows it is an element of the second. If this is not what you meant can you clarify which part?

Comment: all makes sense now. Thanks

Comment: Ah I see you already clarified. Yes, this exactly follows from what was copied before. Is that proof unclear?

Comment: It was a bit unclear to me. Maybe I am just being slow today...

Comment: It happens to us all! Glad it got clarified. Good luck!